# gsub returning more than regex match

Tags: r, regex

I have strings like so

```
x = c(
"blahblah, blah blah, Plate 3, blah blah"
,
"blah blah, blah_Plate 2_blah, blah"
,
"blah, blah, blah blah, blah plate_3"
,
"blah blah, blah, plate 5.txt"
)
```

I want to get the plate number from all of these file names,

so I am testing my regex match with

```
 gsub("\\<Plate\\>.[0-9]","\\1",workdf_nums_plats$Bioplex_Files)
```

so I can eventually do something like this

```
workdf_nums_plats$plat <- ifelse(grepl("\\<Plate\\>.[0-9]", workdf_nums_plats$Bioplex_Files), gsub("\\<Plate\\>.[0-9]","\\1",workdf_nums_plats$Bioplex_Files), NA)
```

I am getting the whole string back on return, I tried using \b to set word boundries but that didn't help.

Any advice would be great thanks!

Comment: seems like you found these answers helpful. Consider accepting the one most helpful to you (check mark to the left of answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a capturing group inside and match `plate` in a case insensitive way, but not as a whole word since you need to match it after `_` (and it is a word char, too):

```
workdf_nums_plats$plat <- sub(".*?Plate.([0-9]+).*","\\1", workdf_nums_plats$Bioplex_Files, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MnTFHf/1) and an R demo below:

```
Bioplex_Files <- c("blahblah, blah blah, Plate 3, blah blah", "blah blah, blah_Plate 2_blah, blah", "blah, blah, blah blah, blah plate_3", "blah blah, blah, plate 5.txt")
plat <- sub(".*?Plate.([0-9]+).*","\\1", Bioplex_Files, ignore.case=TRUE)
plat
## => [1] "3" "2" "3" "5"
```

**Pattern details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `Plate` - `plate` substring (case insensitively due to `ignore.case=TRUE`)
- `.` - any char
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern) matching 1 or more digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, up to the end of string.

If you want to match `Plate` as a whole word, you may prepend the `Plate` with `(?:_|\b)` pattern, [`".*?(?:_|\\b)Plate.([0-9]+).*"`](https://regex101.com/r/MnTFHf/2). Here, `(?:_|\b)` is a non-capturing group (i.e. it does not create a `$2` or `$1`, etc.) that matches either `_` or a word boundary.

An alternative solution is *matching* the values you need, and it is convenient to use *stringr* for this purpose:

```
> str_extract(Bioplex_Files, "(?i)(?<=Plate.)[0-9]+")
[1] "3" "2" "3" "5"
```

Here, `(?i)` is a case insensitive flag, `(?<=Plate.)` is a positive lookbehind that asserts there is `Plate` and any char after it immediately before the `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits (and only the digits are retured since the lookbehind pattern is a zero length assertion, i.e. it does not add text to the match value).

Comment: thanks for helping me understand with my own solution and providing alternatives solutions!

Comment: @AwesomeeExpress Just wanted to let know you can also use `str_match(Bioplex_Files, "(?i)(?:_|\\b)Plate.([0-9]+)")[,2]`. Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `regmatches` with `regexec` to return the captured subexpressions.

```
regmatches(test, regexec("[Pp]late.?([0-9]+)", test))
[[1]]
[1] "Plate 3" "3"      

[[2]]
[1] "Plate 2" "2"      

[[3]]
[1] "plate_3" "3"      

[[4]]
[1] "plate 5" "5"
```

Here, [Pp] will match either "P" or "p",  "late" matches itself literally, ".?" matches 0 or 1 of any character, "()" captures the desired values, which are "[0-9]+", one or more digits.

Since this returns a list, you want to use `sapply` to pull out the second element from each list item like this.

```
sapply(regmatches(test, regexec("[Pp]late.?([0-9]+)", test)), "[", 2)
[1] "3" "2" "3" "5"
```

**data**

```
test <- 
c("blahblah, blah blah, Plate 3, blah blah", "blah blah, blah_Plate 2_blah, blah", 
"blah, blah, blah blah, blah plate_3", "blah blah, blah, plate 5.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is more elegant than mine, regex is very ...deep!